# In Xcode5 test fails with the message IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios7, xcode5

Adding a new Test target to my existing project in Xcode 5.0.2 (XCTest) does not work although it succeeds when compiling the Test Target.

I've already searched here but without success.

Extra info:

**This is an iOS app
Deployment Target is 7.0
It's using two sub-Projects(static library) with resource bundle**

Here's the error message:


`2014-03-19 11:31:06.509 MyProject[53196:70b] Error loading /Users/rodrigoarantes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IgnitEdu-dcshcxphrysxcqdftuszmgdoweuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProjectTests.xctest/MyProjectTests:  dlopen(/Users/rodrigoarantes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IgnitEdu-dcshcxphrysxcqdftuszmgdoweuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProjectTests.xctest/MyProjectTests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/rodrigoarantes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IgnitEdu-dcshcxphrysxcqdftuszmgdoweuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProjectTests.xctest/MyProjectTests: mach-o, but wrong architecture
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/rodrigoarantes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IgnitEdu-dcshcxphrysxcqdftuszmgdoweuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProjectTests.xctest'`

How can I fix this error?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: The problem can be in bundles: Test bundle isn't main bundle of the app. So check in your unit test target settings at the Build Phases tab. Is there that library or image? Also how do you load bundle resources: because, for example `[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];` will fail if, you try to run tests. The same for images - code `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeImage" ofType:@"png"];` also will fail. You should use `[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"SomeImage" ofType:@"png"];` to load something